# problem with query menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

im trying to make a menu with with JQuery, it works good when i'm using one menu-item, but when i'trying to implement a second menu-item, it is displayed at the middle of the previous menu item...

[Here's a demo of what im trying to do](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxvkN/13/)

Comment: It's on the link, theres a live demo on jsFiddle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, never use tables for non-tabular data.

Second, add "float: left" to your `.menu` class.

```
.menu
{
    width:150px;
    float: left;
}
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZxvkN/19/

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the CSS styling, then I think all you'd need to do is set the vertical alignment of the table cell to the top.

```
table td{
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Back into a forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpPuB/)...

To combat the comment below... ;)
I've removed the table from [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fef7k/) and replaced with a DIV. Also added a bit of extra style to the menu class.

Comment: Evil to support his use of tables!  For shame, sir.  For shame.

Comment: Ha! challenge accepted! (and i didn't cheat by looking at your answer). We appear to have come up with different solutions too.

Comment: I wasn't downing on your answer's accuracy, it fixes the problem, but merely saying that you should take it a step further to correct the underlying issue that expressed this problem: his use of tables.

Comment: Never took offence :) And you are right about tables being a problem, though they weren't necessarily the cause. It helps to show both solutions (the fix, and the ideal fix). (Though, in some cases that could allow people to blindly copy whatever they want and not read - but oh well..)

Answer (score 1):

```
table td{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

It will work perfectly.